# Substitution in a system of ordinary differential equations when terms of the same order derivative for different variables occur in the same equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, systems-of-equations

Let's say I have a differential equation such as:

```
y'' - 2ty' + y = 0, y(0) = 2.1, y'(0) = 1.0
```

I can solve this (among other ways) by substitution and conversion to a system of differential equations:

```
w1 = y
w2 = y'

w1' = w2
w2' = 2tw2 - w1
w1(0) = 2.1
w2(0) = 1.0
```

Of course, if we start *out* with a system of differential equations, in certain cases, we can create a larger system via further substitutions.

My question is this: what if I start out with a system in which the highest order for the derivative of more than one variable appears in the same equation?  For example:

```
q'' - 3r'q + r'' = 0
q'' + 5rq + 2r'' = 0
```

(I'm leaving out initial conditions here; just pick your own)
I have been able to get it to work out for may problems by fudging things using Laplace transforms.
But *is* there a substitution I can use on a problem like this?  I've searched online and even some of the literature, but I can't seem to find anything.  Maybe I'm just using the wrong terms.  I realize there are other ways to do this.  Just wondering if there's a substitution that will work.

Comment: You can single out $r''$ and $q''$ terms to obtain a new set of equivalent differential equations.

Comment: I suppose in this case you could, but what about in general?
And while I have what I think is a solution to the problem provided, how would you "single out the r'' and q'' terms"?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you completely. But consider $r'' = -3r'q - 5rq$ and $q'' = 6r'q + 5rq$.

Comment: I guess what I'm wondering is if there is a generic, "magic bullet" substitution for these systems?

Comment: And I tried the substitution method you suggested for that problem.  It works.